# Distance between two waypoints HERE MAPS ROUTING API

Tags: routes, here-api, here-maps-rest

I was wondering whether anyone could help me figure out how to receive the distance between two waypoints information from Here Maps using a Data poller written in js.

The following is the query function:

```
function SetOptions(objectDict) {
routeOptions = {
    uri: 'https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?',
    qs: {
        waypoint0: 'geo!' + objectDict["startLatitude"] + "," + objectDict["startLongitude"],
        
        waypoint1: 'geo!' 'stopover!' + objectDict["StopOverPoint1Latitude"] + "," + objectDict["StopOverPoint1Longitude"],  
        waypoint2: 'geo!' 'stopover!' + objectDict["StopOverPoint2Latitude"] + "," + objectDict["StopOverPoint2Longitude"],             //waypoint as stopoverpoint can be added here
        
        waypoint3: 'geo!' + objectDict["destinationLatitude"] + "," + objectDict["destinationLongitude"],
        mode: 'fastest;car;traffic:enabled',
        jsonAttributes: 1,
        linkAttributes: 'sh,sl,ds', // shape, speedlimit, dynamic speed info
        routeAttributes: 'waypoints,shape,boundingBox',
        legAttributes: 'boundingBox,shape',
        returnElevation: true,   //to recieve Elevation information along with lat & long
        maneuverAttributes: 'po,sh,rn,sp,rs,sa,sq', 
        representation: 'turnByTurn', 
        app_id: 'xxx',
        app_code: 'xxxxx'
    }
}

startHereRequest(routeOptions);
```

}

While the following collects the return information of the API

```
function startHereRequest(option) {
request(option, function (error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);

    var longitudes = [];
    var latitudes = [];
    var speedLimits = [];
    var jamFactors = [];    
    var trafficTimes = [];
    var trafficSpeeds = [];
    var elevation = [];
    var baseSpeeds = [];
    var baseTimes = [];
    //(Beware of same Name )
    if (data.response !== undefined) {
        data.response.route[0].leg.forEach(legs => {
            legs.link.forEach(links => {
                speedLimits.push(links.speedLimit);
                
                var geo = links.shape[0].split(",");
                latitudes.push(parseFloat(geo[0]));
                longitudes.push(parseFloat(geo[1])); 
                elevation.push(parseFloat(geo[2]));
                jamFactors.push(links.dynamicSpeedInfo.jamFactor);
                // api documentation to recieve values (push);
                trafficTimes.push(links.dynamicSpeedInfo.trafficTime);
                trafficSpeeds.push(links.dynamicSpeedInfo.trafficSpeed);
                baseSpeeds.push(links.dynamicSpeedInfo.baseSpeed);
                baseTimes.push(links.dynamicSpeedInfo.baseTime);
                
            });
        });
        var result = { longitudes: longitudes, latitudes: latitudes, speedLimits: speedLimits, jamFactors: jamFactors, trafficTimes: trafficTimes, elevation:elevation, trafficSpeeds:trafficSpeeds, baseSpeeds:baseSpeeds, baseTimes:baseTimes  };
        SetObject("PM/ds/waypointsLatitude", latitudes);
        SetObject("PM/ds/waypointsLongitude", longitudes);
        SetObject("PM/ds/waypointsSpeedlimit", speedLimits);
        SetObject("PM/ds/waypointsTrafficTimes", trafficTimes);
        SetObject("PM/ds/waypointsJamFactors", jamFactors); 
        SetObject("PM/ds/waypointsGradient", elevation);
        SetObject("PM/ds/waypointsBaseSpeed", baseSpeeds);
        SetObject("PM/ds/waypointsBaseTime", baseTimes);
        SetObject("PM/ds/waypointsTrafficSpeed", trafficSpeeds);
        console.log(latitudes);
        // fs.writeFileSync("./results/results.json", JSON.stringify(result));
        // fs.writeFileSync("./results/rawdata.json", JSON.stringify(data.response.route[0]));
    } else {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

}

I already have an offline function using the Haversine formula to calculate the distance between two waypoints, however it seems like there is a possibility to provide this information directly from Here Maps.

Answer (score 0):

To get the distance  between two waypoints ,you have to pass the sm i.e summary tag  in the legAttributes in the request query.Then the summary details will be returned for each legs in the response.For reference please refer the below request query  and response packet.

Sample Request:
.../routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?
routeattributes=wp,sm,lg&
mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&
legattributes=wp,sm&
maneuverattributes=none&
language=en-us&
jsonattributes=41&
metricsystem=metric&
waypoint0=geo!stopOver!33.165198,74.233981&
waypoint1=geo!stopOver!30.84323,75.41767&
waypoint2=geo!stopOver!28.63409,77.21693;;End&
app_code={your_aap_code}
app_id={your_app_id}

Sample Response screenhot with distance between two way points.

[image]